# Best approach for merging similar tables into one in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

so my question might be a bit lengthy but i'll start with the end result that I want.

for example: i have 3 tables that are called Config Items, all three of them come from different sources, and also include similar columns but some columns are different.
What i want is, i want to be able to bring the tables into ADF, and build a pipeline or a workflow that  merges all 3 tables into one, and adds the extra columns too. something like below.
My sink destination is going to be Table storage in Data Lake.

Table 1:

| ID | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 145 | B |

Table 2:

| ID | Item | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | F | Grey |
| 120 | G | White |

Table 3:

| ID | Item | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | X | Black | 10/01/21 |
| 230 | Y | Red | 11/01/21 |

Result:

| ID | Item | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A |  |  |
| 145 | B |  |  |
| 100 | F | Grey |  |
| 120 | G | White |  |
| 200 | X | Black | 10/01/21 |
| 230 | Y | Red | 11/01/21 |

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Union activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union) is what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ray, this maybe leading into a new question, but what do you think would be the best approach to take when it comes to loading the data from different sources. For example in this case we are getting config items from 3 different sources, is it better to store it in blob or table storage in data lake. we do need to identify which source the data or rows are coming in from

Comment: From my personal experience as an ETL developer, usually how the sources are stored are out of my control. As long as I can unify them and abstract them as a single data source(like what you are doing), I will be satisfied. But of course from ADF's perspective, I think it is likely a better option to store the sources in various Azure component. You can minimize the data transfer latency and integration effort as ADF support most of that out-of-the-box.